# Android: Write to a global variable from onItemSelected() method

Tags: android, spinner

I got following issue:

Please see my code

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDay);

    switch (parent.getId())
    {
        case R.id.spinnerMonth:
            String monthstring = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            switch (monthstring)
            {
                case "Januar": month = 1; break;
                case "Februar": month = 2; break;
                case "März": month = 3; break;
                case "April": month = 4; break;
                case "Mai": month = 5; break;
                case "Juni": month = 6; break;
                case "Juli": month = 7; break;
                case "August": month = 8; break;
                case "September": month = 9; break;
                case "Oktober": month = 10; break;
                case "November": month = 11; break;
                case "Dezember": month = 12; break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerDay:
            day = Integer.parseInt(spinner2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            break;
    }

    TextView textDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    textDate.setText(""+month+"---"+day);
}
```

private void setEvents() {

```
    String date = ""+day+"."+month+".";
    //String date = ""+this.getDate();
    textLine1.setText(date);
```

Inside the onItemSelected method I get the correct values for month and day - but in setEvents method I get values of 0 and 0 for month and day. Both variables are declared as global.

Where do I miss something?

Thanks for helping me out
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try to call setEvents() onItemSelected when you select month and date from spinner.